# Loader (processing icon) not displaying during exportToExcel process in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to add loader to (processing icon)  to display during the process `exportToExcel()`, below is my HTML and controller code. Export to excel is an existing functionality works well and now I am adding the loader which should display during the export functionality, and I choose to use a flag then set it (counterFlag) to true at begin of the function and false at end of the function, but it never works for me during the function execution, but I see the loader displaying after the function (exportToExcel) quits and it never gets off. I expect the loader to start display on click of the `exportToExcel()` and off as the export completes. Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Environment**: AngularJs 1.5

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-if="pipeline.counterFlag" id="layoutContent" class="loader"></div>

<div class="adv-search-cs">
  <a class="frame-icon" href="">
    <span class="fa fa-file-excel-o xls-sheet" ng-click="pipeline.exportToExcel()" popover-placement="auto bottom-right" ng-attr-title={{pipeline.excelTooltip}}></span>
    <iframe data-ng-hide="true" id="miPipelineIFrame">
      Your browser does not support inline frames.
    </iframe>
  </a>
</div>
```

Note: class="loader" contains the loader image.

**Controller**:

```
public exportToExcel(): void {
  //hidden code        
  this.counterFlag = true;
  let url: string = this.config.apiUrl + '/transform/export/excel/mipipeline';
  let queryParams: wsModels.ApplicationSearchFilterVO = tempMainVO;
  url += this.timeUtilService.getQueryParamString(queryParams);
  this.iframeForMiPipeline = document.getElementById('miPipelineIFrame');
  $('#miPipelineIFrame').attr('src', url);
  this.counterFlag = false;
}
```

Comment: I dont see you taking control of any async task for where you can have a definitive start and an end. I only see sync code here. You need to look into onLoad function iframe dom element.

Comment: @Axar, The editor's intelligence is not showing "onLoad" method on $('#miPipelineIFrame').attr('src', url);. so can you please provide me few more details about how to convert my code to asynch or an example please.